# I only need one character,if user input several characters, how to print error message?

Tags: c, input, char, scanf

- I use `scanf("%c",...)` to obtain users' input.
- I only need one    character such as **'1'** or **'Q'**.
- If a user input **2,5** or    **1242**,`scanf` can get the first
  character. other characters stay in the buffer. But I don't want the first     character of several characters, I only
  need a single character
- I don't know how to handle this condition then to print a error
  message.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char input;

    if(scanf("%c", &input) == 1){
        if(input != '1' && input != 'Q' || getchar() != '\n'){
            fprintf(stderr, "input error!\n");
            while(getchar() != '\n');//clear input
        } else {
            printf("your input is %c\n", input);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't want the first character of several characters, I only need a single character... if the input is **1,3**,  it should print a error message.

Comment: @sakurababy this get only single character. if the input is **1.388 print error message. if the input is 1,3, _scanf can get the first character. other characters stay in the buffer._

Comment: I mean if the input is **1,3**, I don't want scanf get the first character, it should print an error message and clear buffer.@BLUEPIXY

Comment: @sakurababy I think differently from the posted conditions. _other characters stay in the buffer._ <--> _clear buffer_, Edit the question.

Comment: I mean scanf can do this ->(get the first character and other characters stay in the buffer),But I don't want it do this, I want it print an error message, maybe you don't notice **but**. Anyway , could you help me?

Comment: @sakurababy I edit answer. try this.

Comment: it can work! But there is a warning.. if I add **()** to (input != '1' && input != '2' && input !='3'......),I should enter twice in my program.

Comment: @sakurababy  your code add into your post.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? (scan for a string rather than a character):

```
char buf[10];
printf("Enter a single character: ");
scanf("%s", buf);
if ( strlen( buf ) != 1 )
    printf("Error");
```

Comment: But I need these numbers to compare, if it's a string, it can't be compared..